# Spring Framework hosting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-hosting

I am trying Java with Spring Framework for my own web project. I've asked some traditional JSP web hosting firms which supports Tomcat and they said they do not support Spring Framework. I am confused about this situation. What is the different requirements between JSP and Spring Framework? I was thinking both of them runs on JVM such as Tomcat and they do not need any difference things. Does Spring Framework need different jar files, or different  software on server?

Comment: Just ask for an Apache Tomcat application server - it will be enough to deploy and run any web application (Spring or Spring Boot based). Try Jelastic Cloud - they provide all required infrastructure "from the box".

Comment: I asked and as  I know standart JSP apps also need Tomcat.  Here is the one  of the  hosting firm whicj  I asked ; [link](http://www.alfaserver.net/index.php?s=paketdetay&id=1)

Answer (score 1):

Building a Spring application results in a `jar` with an **embedded webserver** (most of the times tomcat, but you can change this in the `pom.xml`/`build.gradle`).

I used to host my Spring applications on a VPS or Amazon EC2 instance. Something like that. You can just install Java on it and run your jar. No extra installations of webservers needed.

Comment: No it doesn't... It can with Spring Boot, but building a regular application and adding Spring to it doesn't result in a jar but a normal war. Spring != Spring Boot.

Comment: Spring (or even Spring Boot) can produce a `war` file.

Comment: True, I guess that if you produce a war file there is no problem hosting it on a traditional tomcat application server...

Comment: Well, technically Spring doesn't produce any artifact at all. It all depends on the build system.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let get it straight, just summarizing what have been said:

1. Use Spring MVC, without spring boot.
2. Use Spring Boot, and create a war file.